# get a path of deeply nested object by key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a deeply nested object

```
const myObject = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: [
                {
                    t: {finallyHere: 'no!'}
                },
                {
                    d: {finallyHere: 'yes!'}
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

my output object would look like, `output = [a, b, c, 1, d]`
the function I will pass is `getPath(myObject, 'd')`

function I am trying so far,

```
function getPath(obj, key) {
    paths = []

    function getPaths(obj, path) {
        if (obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array)) {
            for (var k in obj){
                paths.push(path + "." + k)
                getPaths(obj[k], path + "." + k)
            }
        }
    }

    getPaths(obj, "")
    return paths.map(function(p) {
        return p.slice(p.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) == key ? p.slice(1) : ''
    }).sort(function(a, b) {return b.split(".").length - a.split(".").length;})[0];
}
```

for which I am getting undefined, please help with the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach and check if the value is an object and if the key exists.

If not iterate the keys and return if the nested call of the function returns a truthy value and return immediately.

```js
const
    getPath = (o, target) => {
        if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') return;
        if (target in o) return [target];
        for (const k in o) {
            const temp = getPath(o[k], target);
            if (temp) return [k, ...temp];
        }
    };
    object = { a: { b: { c: [{ t: { finallyHere: 'no!' } }, { d: { finallyHere: 'yes!' } } ] } } };
    
console.log(getPath(object, 'd'));
```

Comment: This really works, but what if I want to get it based off of an value inside it?
say,     ```object = { a: { b: { c: [{ t: { finallyHere: '123' } }, { d: { finallyHere: '567' } } ] } } };```
and I will pass ```getPath(object, '567')```

Comment: then change the second line to a check with the handed over value `if (o === value) return [target];` and move this line to top.

Comment: Thank you this really helps!